# Javascript Random Name Guesser: Unresponsive Script Issues

Tags: javascript

This is my first post here and I am having trouble wording a question, so please bear with me as I have been on this issue for hours.

My friend and I have thought of a fun little function that is supposed to guess the user's name (through an `<input>` tag) in a certain amount of trials using the random number function to access string letters from an alphabet array numbered 0-25. The function is also supposed to give the user the number of trials it took to guess their name.

I keep getting a non-responsive script, (line 33 - The line containing the second "for loop").

```
var goal = document.getElementById("your_Name").value;
var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
var goalArray = goal.split("");
var trials = 0;
var guessArray = new Array();
var i;
var n;

for (i = 0; i < goalArray.length; i++){
    guessArray.push(alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)]);
}

while (goalArray != guessArray){
    trials++;
    guessArray = [];
    for (n = 0; n < goalArray.length; n++){
    guessArray.push(alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)]);
    }   
}
document.getElementById("appendomatic").innerHTML = "It took " + guessArray + " trials to guess correctly";
```

Any help or attempt to help would be immensely appreciated!

In case anyone was wondering: This little idea of ours was to test the randomness of Javascript's random function through trials (he made the same program in MatLab, so we are going to compare results of the random functions from both languages).

Comment: `goalArray != guessArray` is always true since they are two separate arrays; even if they contain the same elements.

Comment: You need something called deep comparison, Fortunately it's not _that_ expensive given that your arrays don't have a very complex structure. There are some libraries out there can aid this, such as `lodash` and `underscore`

Comment: @woozyking or since they appear to just be arrays of individual letters in `a-z` you could compare them with something like `goalArray + '' != guessArray`, since the `toString()` of the arrays will compare correctly.

Comment: @Paulpro you're right, it's a better technique in this use case

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it to work! I'll one up you when I get the privilege.

Comment: I know this is just for fun, but you're not checking your input. What if the user inputs a very long name? The number of guess increases very much with the length of the input. And what if the user inputs a name with a capital letter (or a dash or anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`goalArray != guessArray` is always true since they are two separate arrays; even if they contain the same elements.

Since they appear to just be arrays of individual letters in a-z you could compare them with something like `goalArray + '' != guessArray`, because the `toString()` of the arrays will compare correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I eventually got it to work (by nesting the while loop and second for loop in another for loop):

```
    var goal = document.getElementById("your_Name").value;
    var goalArray = goal.split("");
    var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    var trials = 0;
    var guessArray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < goalArray.length; i++){
        guessArray.push(alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)]);
    }

    for (x = 0; x < goalArray.length; x++){
        while (goalArray[x] != guessArray[x]){
            trials++;
            guessArray = [];
            for (n = 0; n < goalArray.length; n++){
                guessArray.push(alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)]);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("appendomatic").innerHTML = "It took " + trials + " trials to guess correctly"; 
    }
}
```